# Почему падает программа с ошибкой 1073741845?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtextedit, qplaintextedit

Работаю в *PyCharm*, *Python 3*, пытаюсь получить путь к файлу с помощью данного кода

```
 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(775, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 50, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 240, 121, 21))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 191, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 120, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.listWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 120, 256, 21))
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        self.listWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 190, 256, 21))
        self.listWidget_3.setObjectName("listWidget_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 190, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 90, 191, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 160, 191, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 251, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 775, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл "))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)

            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)
            #self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)
            #self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)

        def getFileName(self):
            filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл для сравнения",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
            self.textEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрали файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>"
                                     "".format(filename, filetype))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    #MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    #ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    #ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    #MainWindow.show()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

При работе открывается окно выбора, но если выбрать файл или нажать отмена или закрыть окно, программа падает с ошибкой

> Process finished with exit code 1073741845

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вообще, вопрос должен содержать минимальный пример, чтобы можно было запустить ваш код и увидеть ошибку, а так можно только гадать. Например, у вас в `getFileName` переменная `lineEdit`, а скорее всего, это виджет `QLineEdit`, а у этого виджета нет метода appendHtml (см. в https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html), значит в этом и ошибка, думаю там будет исключение вида `AttributeError: 'QLineEdit' object has no attribute 'appendHtml'`. Вам нужно или подходящий метод использовать, или другой виджет, типа `QTextEdit`

Comment: @gil9red посмотрите пожалуйста привёл полный код в нём заменил lineEdit на textEdit результат остался тот же.

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, сейчас посмотрю :) Как во втором ответе написали вам нужен виджет QPlainTextEdit, у него есть appendHtml. Или используйте QTextEdit, но с методом `append` вместо `appendHtml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`Всегда запускайте приложение в CMD/консоли/терминале и вы получите реальную ошибку.`**

Класс `QTextEdit` предоставляет виджет, который используется для редактирования и отображения как простого, так и форматированного текста. 
Но `QTextEdit` не имеет свойства `appendHtml`.

Класс `QPlainTextEdit` предоставляет виджет, который используется для редактирования и отображения простого текста. 
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#appendHtml

> void **QPlainTextEdit**::**appendHtml**(const QString &html)
>
> Добавляет новый абзац с HTML в конец редактирования текста.

Вам надо заменить строку:

```
self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
```

на  строку:

```
self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
```

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(775, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 50, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 240, 121, 21))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 20, 191, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 120, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.listWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 120, 256, 21))
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        self.listWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 190, 256, 21))
        self.listWidget_3.setObjectName("listWidget_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(470, 190, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 90, 191, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 160, 191, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        
#        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 251, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 775, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл "))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)

            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)
            #self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)
            #self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)

        def getFileName(self):
            filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
                self,
                "Выбрать файл для сравнения",
                ".",
                "Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)"
            )
            self.textEdit.appendHtml(
                "<br>Выбрали файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>"
                "".format(filename, filetype))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас в том месте происходит ошибка (исключение), которую вы не поймали

Добавьте вокруг кода `try`/`except` и выводите ошибку

Либо, добавьте обработчик не пойманных исключений `sys.excepthook`, [пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/13b6fb9d06765264f64f546822e034a02ee822de/Base64_examples/gui_base64.py#L34):

```
import sys
import traceback

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
...

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    print(text)
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit(1)


sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

...
```

---

Для виджета `QTextEdit` используйте метод [append](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#append):

```
def getFileName(self):
    filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл для сравнения",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
    text = "<br>Выбрали файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>".format(filename, filetype)
    self.textEdit.append(text)
```